# Start Rundeck at system startup

Tags: ubuntu, rundeck

I would like to start Rundeck at system startup.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and manually I start it like this:

```
cd $RDECK_BASE    
java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024m -jar rundeck-launcher-2.6.2.jar
```

I have put the same thing in rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

cd $RDECK_BASE    
java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024m -jar rundeck-launcher-2.6.2.jar
exit 0
```

It won't launch after system reboot. Do you have any explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use .deb file to install it and init script to start it.
Get it [LINK](http://rundeck.org/downloads.html)